# How to override/hide methods with optional parameters?

Tags: typescript

Please see comments below:

```
class MyClassA {
    constructor(optionalParam?: any) {
    }

    initialize(optionalParam?: any) {
    }   
}

class MyClassB extends MyClassA {
    constructor(requiredParam: any) {
        super(requiredParam);
        // OK.
    }

    // I want to override this method and make the param required
    // I can add the private modifier but I want it to
    // be public and hide the method with optionalParam
    initialize(requiredParam: any) {
        // compiler error!
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also posted question [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/431466).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is stopping you from violating the contract of inheritance -- the proposed `MyClassB` cannot be used as a stand-in for `MyClassA`.

Consider:

```
var x = new MyClassB(); // Create a new MyClassB
var y: MyClassA = x;    // OK
y.initialize();         // OK... but MyClassB isn't going to get a value for requiredParam
```

You can refactor so that `MyClassB` doesn't derive from `MyClassA`, or any number of other options.

Comment: You're correct. I checked and the opposite is possible. ie. to have a method with required parameter on the parent and then override it as method with optional parameter on the child. Thanks!